# Autofac variable name based injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to inject some **ValueType** variable values using autofac,  as we do same for Interfaces. I don't want to additionally mention in bootstrapper that this class have named parameterized injection or with Key.

For eg: This is easily injectable

**Registration** =>

```
builder.RegisterType<SqlProvider>().As<ISqlProvider>();
```

**Injection**=>

```
MyClass(ISqlProvider provider)
```

So Can we do something like:

**Registration** =>

```
builder.RegisterType<int>().Named<int>("maxRetries");
```

**Injection**=>

```
MyClass(int maxRetries)
```

Comment: Where is the registration for `MyClass` and why can't it use [named parameters in registration](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html)?

Comment: Why to register MyClass it will automatically inject

Comment: Autofac can only do DI on things it knows about. It won't inject into MyClass unless you register it. Have you actually written any of this code to try out or is it all hypothetical?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is property injection.

http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html

You could for the sake of simplicity use a factory or settingsprovider just like your sqlprovider.

Because i think you want to create some servicelayer.
Pseudocode:

```
private iSqlProvider _sqlprovider;
private ISettingsProvider _settingsProvider;
MyClass(ISqlProvider sqlprovider, ISettingProvider settingProvider)
{
_sqlprovider = sqlprovider;
_settingsProvider = settingsProvider

}
public MyClassModel GetMyAwesomeModels()
{
var settings = _setingsprovider.getSetting()
settings.maxTries
 //do your magic with maxtries
}
```

Comment: I have cleary mentioned a valuetype need to be injected

Comment: Please follow the link http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html

It explain multiple solutions how to inject properties or build your MyClass object.

This is the snipper you seek in the documentation page 

If you have one specific property and value to wire up, you can use the WithProperty() modifier:

builder.RegisterType<A>().WithProperty("PropertyName", propertyValue);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom parameter and a module to have this feature.

A module allows you to add custom parameter for every registration. A parameter is a special class that *Autofac* will call each time a registration is resolved to check whether it can provide the requested parameter.

For example :

```
public class ResolvedNamedParameter : Parameter
{
    public override Boolean CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo pi, 
                                           IComponentContext context, 
                                           out Func<Object> valueProvider)
    {
        if (pi.ParameterType.IsValueType 
            && context.IsRegisteredWithName(pi.Name, pi.ParameterType))
        {
            valueProvider = () => context.ResolveNamed(pi.Name, pi.ParameterType);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            valueProvider = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the module to add the parameter for every registration :

```
public class ResolvedNamedParameterModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
                                                          IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Parameters = new Parameter[] { new ResolvedNamedParameter() }.Concat(e.Parameters);
        };
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```
 builder.RegisterModule<ResolvedNamedParameterModule>();
 builder.Register(c => 3).Named<Int32>("x");
 builder.Register(c => 5).Named<Int32>("y");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Injection=>**

```
MyClass([KeyFilter("maxRetries")]int maxRetries)
```

Is that what you were looking for?